# django condition aggregate foreign key by value

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

**TL;DR**
I want to make the long annotated query (at the project object manager part below) more elegant and efficient, and able to recalculate it self after related object was updated.

**Background**
I'm building a market place - every customer should be able to create a project that contains parts. The parts are the objects up for pricing offers.

Every part contains a status Enum field - so we could know if it up to bid or already in work.

**Im Using**

- Python 3.8.1
- Django-rest-framework 3.10.3
- [django-url-filter 0.3.14](https://github.com/miki725/django-url-filter)
- Postgres 12.1

**The functionality I need**

- Projects should be filtered by their contained parts status - with specific conditions.
- Update on the project status should update all related parts.
- Projects can be created, update and deleted with the same object manager.

**Part Model**
Only relevant parts of the code:

```py
class PartStatuses(Enum):
    Draft = "Saved but not published"
    PendingBID = "It's BIDing time!"
    Proposal = "All BIDs are set"
    PendingPO = "Waiting for vendor to approve PO"
    WorkInProgress = "Vendor has accepted a PO"
    OnItsWay = "The part is ready and now await to be delivered"
    Delivered = "Delivery process has ended"
    Disputed = "Open for Dispute"
    Closed = "Part has received"
    Paid = "Vendor received the payment"

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(key.name, key.value) for key in cls]

class Part(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='part')
    status = models.CharField(choices=PartStatuses.choices(),
                              max_length=100,
                              default=PartStatuses.Draft)
    ...
```

**Projects Model**
At first, I tried using property method for the project status field and setter method for the parts status update.

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False,
                              limit_choices_to={'is_vendor': False})
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ...

    def got_parts(self):
        return self.part.count()

    @property
    def _status(self):
        if self.got_parts(): 
            all_parts: object = self.part.values_list('status')

            # Project is done and paid
            if all_parts.filter(status=PartStatuses.Paid.value).count() == all_parts.count():
                return str(PartStatuses.Paid.name)

            # At least one parts are open for disputed
            if all_parts.filter(status=PartStatuses.Disputed.value).count() > 0:
                return str(PartStatuses.Disputed.name)

            # Some parts are draft
            if all_parts.filter(status=PartStatuses.Draft.value).count() > 0:
                return str(PartStatuses.Draft.name)

            # Some parts are pending to bid
            if all_parts.filter(status=PartStatuses.PendingBID.value).count() > 0:
                return str(PartStatuses.PendingBID.name)

            # Some parts are on proposal
            if all_parts.filter(status=PartStatuses.Proposal.value).count() > 0:
                return str(PartStatuses.Proposal.name)

            # Some parts are pending to vendor approve PO
            if all_parts.filter(status=PartStatuses.PendingPO.value).count() > 0:
                return str(PartStatuses.PendingPO.name)

            # Some parts are in progress of working
            if all_parts.filter(status=PartStatuses.WorkInProgress.value).count() > 0:
                return str(PartStatuses.WorkInProgress.name)

            # Some parts are on their way
            if all_parts.filter(status=PartStatuses.OnItsWay.value).count() > 0:
                return str(PartStatuses.OnItsWay.name)

            # Some parts has been marked by delivery guys as delivered
            if all_parts.filter(status=PartStatuses.Delivered.value).count() > 0:
                return str(PartStatuses.Delivered.name)

            # Some parts has been marked by customer as delivered
            if all_parts.filter(status=PartStatuses.Closed.value).count() > 0:
                return str(PartStatuses.Closed.name)

            # Error with the parts status mapping
            return "Other"

        else:  # No parts - this projects is draft
            return str(PartStatuses.Draft.name)

    @_status.setter
    def _status(self, status):
        if any(k[0] == status for k in PartStatuses.choices()) and self.got_parts():
            for part in self.part.all():
                part.status = PartStatuses[status].value
                part.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Soon I realized there is no option to query this property as a field, a quote from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups):

> The field specified in a lookup has to be the name of a model field

So I had to add my own custom object manager with the same conditioning as the status model property:

```py
class ProjectManager(models.Manager):
    """QuerySet manager for Project class to add non-database fields."""

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Overrides the models.Manager method"""
        qs = super().get_queryset().annotate(
            parts_num=Count(F('part'), distinct=True),
            parts_paid=Count(F('part'), filter=Q(part__status__exact=PartStatuses.Paid.value), distinct=True),
            parts_disputed=Count(F('part'), filter=Q(part__status__exact=PartStatuses.Disputed.value), distinct=True),
            parts_draft=Count(F('part'), filter=Q(part__status__exact=PartStatuses.Draft.value), distinct=True),
            parts_pending_bid=Count(F('part'), filter=Q(part__status__exact=PartStatuses.PendingBID.value), distinct=True),
            parts_proposal=Count(F('part'), filter=Q(part__status__exact=PartStatuses.Proposal.value), distinct=True),
            parts_workin_progress=Count(F('part'), filter=Q(part__status__exact=PartStatuses.WorkInProgress.value),
                                        distinct=True),
            parts_pending_PO=Count(F('part'), filter=Q(part__status__exact=PartStatuses.PendingPO.value), distinct=True),
            parts_on_its_way=Count(F('part'), filter=Q(part__status__exact=PartStatuses.OnItsWay.value), distinct=True),
            parts_delivered=Count(F('part'), filter=Q(part__status__exact=PartStatuses.Delivered.value), distinct=True),
            parts_closed=Count(F('part'), filter=Q(part__status__exact=PartStatuses.Closed.value), distinct=True),
        ).annotate(
            status=Case(
                When(parts_num=0, then=Value(PartStatuses.Draft.name)),
                When(parts_paid=F('parts_num'), then=Value(PartStatuses.Paid.name)),
                When(parts_disputed__gt=0, then=Value(PartStatuses.Disputed.name)),
                When(parts_draft__gt=0, then=Value(PartStatuses.Draft.name)),
                When(parts_pending_bid__gt=0, then=Value(PartStatuses.PendingBID.name)),
                When(parts_proposal=F('parts_num'), then=Value(PartStatuses.Proposal.name)),
                When(parts_workin_progress__gt=0, then=Value(PartStatuses.WorkInProgress.name)),
                When(parts_pending_PO__gt=0, then=Value(PartStatuses.PendingPO.name)),
                When(parts_on_its_way__gt=0, then=Value(PartStatuses.OnItsWay.name)),
                When(parts_delivered__gt=0, then=Value(PartStatuses.Delivered.name)),
                When(parts_closed__gt=0, then=Value(PartStatuses.Closed.name)),
                default=Value("Other"),
                output_field=CharField()
            )
        )
        return qs
```

Added the manager to the project model:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    with_status = ProjectManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False,
                              limit_choices_to={'is_vendor': False})
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

And used it on my **Project View**

```py
from url_filter.integrations.drf import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import viewsets

class ProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows projects to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsVendorStaffOrOwner)
    queryset = Project.with_status.prefetch_related('part').all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ('status',)
```

But the I got an error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Project has no field named 'status'`, so I tried to work around it and wrote my own filter class:

```py
from url_filter.filtersets import FilterSet
from django.db.models import Q

class ProjectsDynamicFilters(FilterSet):
    def filter(self):
        all_filters = Q()
        if 'status' in self.data:
            all_filters &= Q(status=self.data['status'])

        if len(all_filters):
            return self.queryset.filter(all_filters).distinct()
        else:
            return self.queryset
```

and use it instead of my `filter_field` property at the project view: `filter_class = ProjectsDynamicFilters`.

At this point, accept the very long and clumsy annotated query at the project object manager, I couldn't update or create objects, because my project serializer has a status field inside, and create or update could not simply return an instance.

Update function specifically is not recalculating status field after updating related parts objects.

**Project Serializer**

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
                                               default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", read_only=True)
    updated_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", read_only=True)

    title = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField()
    status = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=PartStatuses.choices(), default=PartStatuses.Draft.name)
    parts = NestedHyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, source="part", parent_lookup_kwargs={'project_pk': 'project__pk'},
                                          view_name="parts-detail", read_only=True)
    ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for data in validated_data:
            if data == "status":
                instance._status = validated_data.get(data)
            else:
                setattr(instance, data, validated_data.get(data))
        instance.save()
        return Project.with_status.get(pk=instance.id)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop('status', None)
        project = Project.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return Project.with_status.get(pk=project.id)
```

**Back to the questions**

1. Is there a way of making the project `with_status` manager query more elegant and efficient?
2. At the moment I keep the `_status` model property only for the `setter` function I use to update project with status. is there a way making this function available at model level without making this calculation again?
3. Once I change part status the project status field should be re-calculated. I worked around it by returning `Project.with_status.get(pk=instance.id)` at the end of the update serializer method. Is there a wiser way doing it?

Comment: I don't understand "making this function available at the model level without making this calculation again". How many times during one request do you need to access this? Since it's a calculated value you only need to calculate it when you need to display it.

Comment: Just a direction to explore: Since it seems your calculated status is the first one you hit if a part has that status (in a specific order), you might want to assign numeric values to the statuses explicitly and just fetch the minimum value: `Project.objects.annotate(status=Min('part__status'))`. However it makes it difficult to add a new status later on.

Comment: @dirkgroten About the first comment: The intention is: How can I use the setter functionality without the `_status` property content (which is the same calculation as the object manager query)

Comment: You want a setter but no getter? That’s not possible. Just call the method `set_status()` then.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your ENUM:

```
class PartStatuses(Enum):
    Draft = 0, _("Saved but not published")
    PendingBID = 1, _("It's BIDing time!")
    Proposal = 2, _("All BIDs are set")
    PendingPO = 3, _("Waiting for vendor to approve PO")
    WorkInProgress = 4, _("Vendor has accepted a PO")
    OnItsWay = 5, _("The part is ready and now await to be delivered")
    Delivered = 6, _("Delivery process has ended")
    Disputed = 7, _("Open for Dispute")
    Closed = 8, _("Part has received")
    Paid = 9, _("Vendor received the payment")
```

That way you can keep your Enum values as a label and use `Min()` function on the Project Manager annotated query.